# Highcharts angular dependency-wheel

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have been trying to implement the dependency-wheel chart from the Highcharts-angular Library: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

I made a simple stackBlitz with minimal configuration but i keep getting error #17 : The requested series type does not exist.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmmban?file=src/app/app.component.html

Why is it not working? i tried adding it in the import statements but there is no ts file to import for some charts (the dependency-wheel being among them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that dependency-wheel requires two extra modules to render - sankey.js and dependendency-wheel.js. Importing them to your app will fix the error.

```
import HC_sankey from 'highcharts/modules/sankey';
import HC_depwheel from 'highcharts/modules/dependency-wheel';

HC_sankey(Highcharts);
HC_depwheel(Highcharts);
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3cdwh1?file=src/app/app.component.ts

---

API: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/dependency-wheel

Comment: Thank you so much. this seems to be working. The highchats-angular documentation is kinda lacking and very minimalistic. Can I ask you where did you find the information to add sankey ?

Comment: Hm, you got right in official API documentation there is only information about dependency-wheel module - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.dependencywheel. There is a lack of information about the Sankey module. Could you report it on the Highcharts Github issue channel? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues